# Discord.js v12 - Checking in which channel a reaction was in a messageReactionAdd Event

Tags: discord.js

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user, message) => {

 if(user.bot) return;
 if(!message.channel.id === "915245191911309383") return

 console.log("ADD")

})
```

My Error code:

```
/home/runner/Mondlw/index.js:328
 if(!message.channel.id === "915245191911309383") return
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Mondlw/index.js:328:14)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageReactionAdd.handle (/home/runner/Mondlw/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageReactionAdd.js:49:17)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD] (/home/runner/Mondlw/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD.js:4:37)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/Mondlw/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/Mondlw/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/Mondlw/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/Mondlw/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
```

**What i wanna do: If reaction was added to a message -> check if reaction was made by bot -> check if reaction was in specific channel -> do my code**

Answer (score 1):

[`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) only gives 2 arguments (A [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) and a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)). Do this instead which gets the [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) from the reaction:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.bot) return;
  if (!reaction.message.channel.id === "915245191911309383") return;
  console.log("ADD")
})
```

Note that you should use `!==` instead as you are checking `false === "xxx"` right now

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.bot) return;
  if (reaction.message.channel.id !== "915245191911309383") return;
  console.log("ADD")
})
```